# Center div horizontally without width with JS

Tags: javascript, center

I'm coding my graduate work and I'm having trouble centering div with contents that change change (image upload).

In my script I create `<img id="uploaded">` and insert the uploaded image into it, and this `<img>` is inserted in `<div id="canvas"></div>`.

In my CSS :

```
#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 500;
}
```

I tried :

```
var canvaswidth = document.getElementById('uploaded').width;
```

for getting the img width, and I want to add a negative left margin for centering my div.

I tried :

```
document.getElementById('canvas').style.marginLeft = - canvaswidth / 2;
```

But that doesn't work. Can you help me make it work?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that rather than trying to calculate its position yourself (complete with division, padding-subtraction), you're better off using auto-margins, and specifying the div's width based on the image's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need units:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').style.marginLeft = - canvaswidth /2 + 'px';
```

However, you could use "absolute centering":

```css
#canvas {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

And just set the `width` to the desired value:

```
document.getElementById('canvas').style.width = canvaswidth + 'px';
```

Comment: Thank you Sir! It works fine, I feel so stupid ... (CSS only did not worked).

Comment: @Oriol: That `left/right/width` trick is well cool ([live example](http://jsbin.com/birexoki/1) for anyone who wants to try it out). I'm not sure that was in my toolkit before... Even works on IE8, of all things.